# std::map<string, int> crashes when doing m[0]

Tags: c++, c++11

The following crashes:

```
  std::map<std::string, int> m1{ {"0", 0}, { "1", 1 }};
  // auto melem = m1["0"]; // OK
  auto melem = m1[0];
```

Why is that?

Comment: `0` is not a string.  Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: Why shouldn't it crash? Argument to `operator[]` must of type `key_type` for given map.

Comment: Because `"0"` is one of the keys and `0` is not. Why do you expect it not to crash, or what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: basic_string( const CharT* s,const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );: Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. *The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range (for example, if s is a null pointer)*.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Answers go below cheers

Comment: @mkrieger1 To be fair, a "crash" for something like this is not logically to be expected.

Comment: @NathanOliver: did I say I was expecting it to work?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: did I say it shouldn't crash?

Comment: @mkrieger1: did I say it shouldn't crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately (thanks C!) it is "possible" to construct a `std::string` from the integer `0`, because it counts as a *null pointer literal*.

However, [it's not *really* possible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by `s`. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if `[s, s + Traits::length(s))` is not a valid range (for example, if `s` is a null pointer).

**You got a crash because you tried to create a `std::string` from a null pointer.**

At least [with GCC the result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df43bea28b0a4e2e) of this contract violation is an [unhandled] exception with a descriptive name:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Unfortunately, though, you can't rely on this, and you don't get any warnings during build.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helping. Indeed, no warning, just a crash. I though this had something to do with the map, but actually not. doing something like std::string s = 0 is enough to make the program crash. Thanks!

Comment: @Korchkidu That's right :)